I am citing a book from 1915. The metadata says it was published in Constantinople. What does the Chicago Manual of Style say about old names?
The book I am citing is Εκκλησιαστική Αλήθεια.
I am already citing another book from “İstanbul.” I do not want to be inconsistent. Yet, the city was officially known as Istanbul in 1915, so it wouldn’t be inaccurate to say it was published in Constantinople.

Always cite a source using the data given in the source. This is a simple rule and it always applies, without exception.
In your reference list,

do not change names of places that have been changed in later times,
do not give the real name of an author if the book was published under a pseudonym
do not change the name of an author who has married and later publications appear under a different name
do not change a publication year given in a source even if it is wrong (e.g. if the volume of a journal for a certain year was actually published at a later date, as is quite frequent; if neccessary, you may do: 1943 (published in 1944))

If for some reason it is necessary for the reader to understand these changes, you may explain them in text (e.g. Smith-Hartman (publishing as Smith, 2010) ...). But it rarely is. The sole purpose of a citation is to credit your source in a way that makes it possible for others to find that source. Not to explain historical facts.

+1, this is it.
